# Best way to convert rows of features into a table with features as the columns

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to convert a csv in which each row represents a user and a  feature about this user into a data table. Each user has multiple rows, each describing one aspect about the user. For example,

```
+---------+---------+
| User Id | Feature |
+---------+---------+
| user_1  | male    |
| user_2  | female  |
| user_1  | teen    |
| user_2  | adult   |
+---------+---------+
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| User Id | male  | female | teen  | adult |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
| user_1  | TRUE  | FALSE  | TRUE  | FALSE |
| user_2  | FALSE | TRUE   | FALSE | TRUE  |
+---------+-------+--------+-------+-------+
```

The code below is what I came up with at first. Unfortunately, R ran out of memory during processing.

```
data <- fread( file="input.csv", 
               col.names=c("userId","feature"), 
               colClasses=c("string", "string"), 
               showProgress=TRUE,
               key=c("userId","feature")
              )


normalizeFunction <- function(featureForOne) {
      as.list(!is.na(match(allFeatures, featureForOne)))
} 

allFeatures = data[, unique(feature)]

normalizedData = data[ , c(allFeatures) := normalizeFunction(role) , keyby=.(userId)]
```

At the end, I had to settle on processing each user one by one in a for loop. Though, I feel like I am not taking advantage of data.table. Can someone comment on my solution?

```
allUsers = unique(data$userId)

normalizedData <- foreach (user = allUsers, .combine=rbind) %do% {
  featuresForUser = data[ userId == user ]
  featuresForUser [ , normalizeFunction(feature), by=.(userId) ]
}

names(normalizedData, c("userId", allFeatures))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, I think:

```
x <- fread('
User_Id Feature
user_1  male   
user_2  female 
user_1  teen   
user_2  adult  ')
```

A temporary variable that we'll use with `fun=any` below:

```
x[,a:=TRUE,]
```

The actual widening:

```
dcast(x, User_Id ~ Feature, fun=any, value.var="a")
#    User_Id adult female  male  teen
# 1:  user_1 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# 2:  user_2  TRUE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

A `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(tmp = TRUE) %>% spread(Feature, tmp) %>% replace(., is.na(.), FALSE)
```

Output:

```
  User_Id adult female  male  teen
1  user_1 FALSE  FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
2  user_2  TRUE   TRUE FALSE FALSE
```